# ContextFlyout Not Working After 1809 Update

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am working on a UWP application and have a `ContextFlyout` attached to a `TextBlock`. Yesterday, everything worked as expected.

This morning, my machine finally got the **1809 update**.  After the update, I launched *VS2017 15.9.7* to continue working on my app.  The `ContextFlout` did not open when the `TextBlock` was '*Right-Clicked*' as it did the day before.

I created a new project with a very simple UI

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="5" Width="200" Height="100">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.ContextFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout x:Name="testFO" Opening="TestFO_Opening">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name="Item1" Text="Bob"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Name ="Item2" Text="Jim"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </TextBlock.ContextFlyout>
                This is a test
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The Menu is not shown.  There are no errors nor in the *TestFO_Opening* event fired.

To confirm that this is an 1809 issue, I copied to project to another development machine with 1803 and it runs as expected.

I have searched the net with little relevant information.  There was one post that suggested using `FlyoutBase.AttachFlyout` as a work around, but workarounds tend to lead to trouble in other places.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Can I ask what OS Build of windows you have experienced this on? I currently have a similar issue on 1809, OS Build 17763.253, but cannot reproduce the issue on 1809, OS Build 17763.316 (the latest and greatest)

Comment: Could you clean all your `bin`/`obj` folder and rebuild?

Comment: Made no difference.  This has been confirmed as a XAML issue with 1809.

Comment: SWallis - my OS build is 316.  Feedback on other forums indicates that the issue may be specific to being attached to a TextBlock, but I have not confirmed that.